# WebSettings.getDisplayZoomControls() returns false, but display zoom controls are still shown

Tags: java, android, webview, zooming

I have a problem in my app. I use WebView in it, and I allow user to define if he wants to display display zoom controls in it trough PreferenceActivity.  Display zoom controls are disabled by default. When i enable them, they starts to show up, but when i try to disable them, they are still visible until i restart app. Here is code handeling situation.

```
     public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
           webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
           webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(webSettings.getBoolean("zoom_controls", false));

Log.d("tag", String.valueOf(websettings.getDisplayZoomControls());`

    }
```

When i try to check if they are showing up with `Log.d("tag", String.valueOf(websettings.getDisplayZoomControls());`, after i disable them it returns false, but they are still on the screen. Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried this one ? webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(webSettings.getBoolean("zoom_controls", false));

Comment: Isn't _false_ the default value of http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29

Comment: I am using setBuiltInZoomControls() in the app, and i setted it to true becouse i need pinch to zoom enabled always, i am using setDisplayZoomControls() becouse i want to show and hide only zoom contorls, i dont want to affect pinch to zoom.